referencing the same device on a software method claim
a computer implemented method, comprising:
receiving a request from a first user using a first electronic device;
sending a response to the first electronic device;
....

If every step of the claim, or interaction with the client, is referenced using "the first electronic device", is this technically limiting the claim to a user only ever using one device to complete an instance of the process?


is this technically limiting the claim to a user only ever using one device to complete an instance of the process?

Yes, but to exploit this a freeloader would have to require all users of their service to change devices at least one during the claimed interaction.
Do you need to specify where the requests come from and where the responses go to?
Let's say the invention is instant messaging:

a) receiving a request in a first session, said first session being logically associated with a first user, said request including a message, said  request identifying a second user as the recipient of said message


b) sending a response in a second session, said second session being logically associated with said second user, said response including said message, said response identifying said first user as the sender of said message

Here the specification would explain that the "response" in (b) is to a poll request from the second user's client, and that "logically associated" means an authentication step or administrative override has linked a session to a user.
Note: This is just to show that one doesn't need to specify the device where the communication goes. There are likely abstract idea problems with such a claim because it has little or no technical content.

In your last sentence "There are likely abstract idea problems with such a claim because it has little or no technical content.", are you referring your whole example. Or are you referring to the use of the session instead of the device as potentially causing the abstract idea problems?

I don't think referencing the device rather than the session makes it less abstract. There are different takes on what abstractedness is supposed to mean but I don't think it's about tangibility. After all a computer is perfectly tangible but we know an abstract idea does not become less abstract with computer implementation.
